# Size of featured image in admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

Been experimenting with some custom meta boxes, but nothing I've read or can find is helping me to achieve what I'm actually after.

I can render a new meta box, but I can't find a way to actually change the output of the post thumbnail itself in the admin panel.

```
function new_post_thumbnail_meta_box() {
    global $post; 

    echo 'Content above the image.';

    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true ); 
    echo _wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id ); 

    echo 'Content below the image.';
}
function render_new_post_thumbnail_meta_box() {
    global $post_type;

    // remove the old meta box
    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','post','side' );

    // adding the new meta box.
    add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image'), 'new_post_thumbnail_meta_box', $post_type, 'side', 'low');
}
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'render_new_post_thumbnail_meta_box');
```

How to have a larger or 'actual size' version of the featured image displayed in the administration panel?

Copied the includes function and modified the output, this throws up a server error.

```
function _wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id = null, $post = null ) {
            global $content_width, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

           $post = get_post( $post );

            $upload_iframe_src = esc_url( get_upload_iframe_src('image', $post->ID ) );
            $set_thumbnail_link = '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="' . esc_attr__( 'Set featured image' ) . '" href="%s" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">%s</a></p>';
            $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, esc_html__( 'Set featured image' ) );

            if ( $thumbnail_id && get_post( $thumbnail_id ) ) {
                    $old_content_width = $content_width;
                    $content_width = 600;
                    if ( !isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['post-thumbnail'] ) )
                            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, array( $content_width, $content_width ) );
                    else
                            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    if ( !empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
                            $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post->ID );
                            $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, $thumbnail_html );
                            $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">' . esc_html__( 'Remove featured image' ) . '</a></p>';
                    }
                    $content_width = $old_content_width;
            }

            return apply_filters( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', $content, $post->ID );
    }
```

Or should I be using add_image_size( 'post_thumbnail', 600, 400, true ); ? since that's what it looks for?

Comment: In what sense do you mean "larger or actual size"? IMO, a screenshot/draft-design would be helpful. Because, once I've seen a bug, where the Featured Image is "full size" and it completely breaks the admin layout, with a horizontal scrollbar showing up and the metabox all overflown.

Comment: @brasofilo It's alright, I'm working on my own customised admin panel, i've completely reworked it (and will be githubbing it once it's finished), it's responsive so there will be no horizontal scrollbars.

The featured image that's displayed in the admin panel is by default 266xrandom px (height depending on the aspect ratio), I want to be able to show the full size featured image whilst editing/writing posts.

Comment: I'd like it to appear actual size or a size I want. Just now it shows up at the default size of featured images in the admin panel. 266x144px usually.

Comment: That'd be great, brasofilo.

Comment: You have to copy the function and ***rename it***.

Comment: @brasofilo when I rename it, it doesn't work, still uses the core function. I guess it's something to do with applying filters to override the core function?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case somebody is stumbling on this old post.

WP introduced a new filter called [admin_post_thumbnail_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_size/) for you to be able to change the default image size in the admin panel.

To change the size of the featured thumbnail image you can use something like this:

```
function custom_admin_thumb_size($thumb_size){
  return "custom-image-size"; //or use something like array(400,400).
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_size', 'custom_admin_thumb_size');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `_wp_post_thumbnail_html` with [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: If I do that it doesn't even give me the 'Set featured Image' box. (I tried it before I made this post too).

Comment: @andy, you should mention that in the Question. So, nobody offers solutions you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in [WordPress 4.4](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_size/), a new filter was introduced, `admin_post_thumbnail_size`, which allows for modifying the display size of the post thumbnail image in the Featured Image meta box.

> When a theme adds ‘post-thumbnail’ support, a special ‘post-thumbnail’ image size is registered, which differs from the ‘thumbnail’ image size managed via the Settings > Media screen.

We can use this filter to alter the `post-thumbnail` size (266 x 266 px) and modify it to use the default `thumbnail` size (150 x 150 px) instead.

```php
/**
 * Change Display Size of Featured Image Thumbnail in WordPress Admin Dashboard
 */
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_size', function ( $size, $thumbnail_id, $post ) {
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    $result = array_search( 'thumbnail', $sizes );

    $size = is_numeric( $result ) ? $sizes[ $result ] : array( 100, 100 );

    return $size;
}, 10, 3 );
```

A specific size (e.g., 100 x 100 px) can also be specified or set as a fallback in case the [intermediate thumbnail size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_intermediate_image_sizes/) isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

The function `_wp_post_thumbnail_html` returns a code like this:

```
<p class="hide-if-no-js">
    <a title="Set featured image" href="http://example.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=4573&#038;type=image&#038;TB_iframe=1" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">
        <img width="266" height="90" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb2-3-846x288.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" alt="thumb2-3" />
    </a>
</p>
<p class="hide-if-no-js">
    <a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail('dfd8f3353b');return false;">
        Remove featured image
    </a>
</p>
```

Note that the image is `846x288`, but it's being resized to `266x90` in the `img` tag attributes.

[Analyzing the function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L1122), we see that if there is an image size named `post_thumbnail`, it will get that one. Otherwise, it gets an image size of `266x266` (with crop). You can simply copy the function and modify to your desired output.

Other option is to use the filter `admin_post_thumbnail_html` and remove the `img` width and height attributtes:

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'filter_featured_img_so_17713997' );

function filter_featured_img_so_17713997( $html )
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if(count($tags) > 0)
    {
           $tag = $tags->item(0);
           $tag->removeAttribute('width');
           $tag->removeAttribute('height');
           return $doc->saveHTML($tag);
    }

    return $html;
}
```

The results may not be what you expect, though. If the image is larger than `266`, it bleeds out of the browser canvas.

Comment: I tried copying in the function and modifying the output, but it just throws me a server error. I'll edit my first post with the code so you can see what sort of stupid thing I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I can edit it directly in the WP core file and get it to work, but that's a no no. Copying the function still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option to use a custom sized thumbnail or the system defined 'full' sized image (the original size of the image you uploaded) as the Featured Image displayed in the admin panel:

```
/**
 * step 1   - define custom image size
 *
 *          - either plan to use 'full' (returns the size of the image you uploaded) OR define our custom image size
 *          - so we can call one of those instead of the system defined default 'post-thumbnail'
 *
 *          - remainder of this example assumes using a custom image size, so it is defined
 *          - if using 'full', instead, then no need to define custom
 *          - so remove the following add_image_size line (and thereby skip step 1)
 */
add_image_size( 'admin-post-thumbnail', 846, 288, true );

/**
 * step 2   - replace the meta box with ours for standard post type only, especially so we can set our own callback and 
 *          - move it into the larger main column.
 *          - Note that in any event, the full size won't ever have greater width than the current column width
 *          - as CSS and modern admin panel make the image elements responsive to the column width.
 */
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'so17713997_move_meta_box');

function so17713997_move_meta_box(){
    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image'), 'so17713997_post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'low');
}

// step 3   - custom callback to call our functional replacement for _wp_post_thumbnail_html for post type only
function so17713997_post_thumbnail_meta_box( $post ) {
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
    echo so17713997_wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id, $post->ID );
}

/**
 * step 4   - replace _wp_post_thumbnail_html with our version that calls our thumbnail 'admin-post-thumbnail' instead of the default 'post-thumbnail'
 *
 *          - we could do more here, like adjust the content width variable, but not entirely necessary. The custom image size we defined will
 *          - handle most of it, plus the admin section these days has responsive CSS, so the image doesn't blow-out column width in any event.
 */
function so17713997_wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id = null, $post = null ) {
    global $content_width, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $post               = get_post( $post );
    $post_type_object   = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
    $set_thumbnail_link = '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="%s" href="%s" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">%s</a></p>';
    $upload_iframe_src  = get_upload_iframe_src( 'image', $post->ID );

    $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link,
        esc_attr( $post_type_object->labels->set_featured_image ),
        esc_url( $upload_iframe_src ),
        esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->set_featured_image )
    );

    if ( $thumbnail_id && get_post( $thumbnail_id ) ) {
        $old_content_width = $content_width;
        $content_width = 266;
        if ( !isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['admin-post-thumbnail'] ) )    // use our custom image size instead of 'post-thumbnail' OR use 'full' for system defined fullsize image
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, array( $content_width, $content_width ) );
        else
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, 'admin-post-thumbnail' ); // use our custom image size instead of 'post-thumbnail' OR use 'full' for system defined fullsize image
        if ( !empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
            $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post->ID );
            $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link,
                esc_attr( $post_type_object->labels->set_featured_image ),
                esc_url( $upload_iframe_src ),
                $thumbnail_html
            );
            $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">' . esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->remove_featured_image ) . '</a></p>';
        }
        $content_width = $old_content_width;
    }

    /**
     * Filter the admin post thumbnail HTML markup to return.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param string $content Admin post thumbnail HTML markup.
     * @param int    $post_id Post ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', $content, $post->ID );
}
```

Note first that the feature image selected may not reflect the updated size until after the post has been Saved or Updated, as appropriate.

Also, this hack makes extensive use of the following core WordPress functions:

[the_post_thumbnail()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail),
[add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box),
post_thumbnail_meta_box(), and
 
_wp_post_thumbnail_html
(I didn't have enough reputation yet to post more than two links, so google them.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the default Featured Image size by using [set_post_thumbnail_size()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size)? I had the same issue and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress Block editor shows Featured Images using square thumbnails by default. To change that, we need to apply a JavaScript filter instead of a PHP filter. A very simple filter to display uncropped Featured Images looks like this:

```js
wp.hooks.addFilter(
  "editor.PostFeaturedImage.imageSize",
  "uncroppedFeaturedImage",
  () => "post-thumbnail"
);
```

Load that script from the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` hook. Other registered image sizes (`medium`, `large`, etc.) can also be used.